# Electric Potential of Conductors

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, solid-state-physics

I understand that charges in a conductor reside on the surface of a conductor. So why is it that the neutral inside of a conductor and the charged surface are at the same potential?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you understand that the electric field within a conductor is zero?  The charge is mobile, so the internal charge rearranges itself until there is no longer any force to move them:  there is no field in the interior.  If you understand that, then you will realize that a test particle within the conductor will feel no force, so no work will be done in moving the charge anywhere inside the conductor.  So every point in the interior is at the same potential.

The same argument applies to the surface.  Surface charges will move until there is no longer a force to move them.  There is no electric field parallel to the surface, so the surface is an equipotential.

Finally, why is the potential at the surface the same as the potential in the bulk?  Same argument, plus the realization that charges can migrate between the surface and the bulk, and will do so until there is no longer any force to move them:  the surface and the bulk will then be at the same potential.

I hope I interpreted your question correctly ... it is a little vaguely worded.